# Shifting a char array prior to adding to it

Tags: c, arrays, insert, char, shift

I want to insert characters into the middle of a char array in C, but first I want to shift it to the right each time prior to adding a char so that I don't lose what's already in the char array (called input) by overwriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are terminating the array with a null char since you are using strlen. In that case, I'm pretty sure the first iteration of your for loop will overwrite the null character with the preceding char, and you don't seem to replace it. Try running

```
    for( k = strlen(input) + 1; k > place42; k--)...
```

This should replace your null character so that your array is properly terminated. Of course you should also be sure  you are not overflowing your array and writing on memory that doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a write a generic insert routine using the standard C string functions? Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// insert "ins" into "src" at location "at"
char *insert(char *src, char *ins, int at) {
        char dst[strlen(src) + strlen(ins) + 1];
        strncpy(dst, src, at);
        strcpy(dst + at, ins);
        strcpy(dst + at + strlen(ins), src + at);
        return strdup(dst);
        //return strcpy(src, dst); // you could return this if you know src is long enough
}

int main(void) {

        char *src = "abcdef";
        char *ins = "123";
        printf("%s\n", insert(src, ins, 3));
        return 0;
}
```

prints

```
abc123def
```